# Build An Array from a list and a dictionnary with Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, matrix

i am trying to build a matrix with a list and then fill it up with the values of dict. It works with small data but the computer crashes when bigger data is used (not enough Ram).
My script is clearly too heavy but i don't see how to improve it (first time in programming). Thanks

```
import numpy as np
liste = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"]

dico = {"a/b": 4, "c/d" : 2, "f/g" : 5, "g/h" : 2}

#now i'd like to build a square array (liste x liste) and fill it up with the values of
# my dict.


def make_array(liste,dico):
    array1 = []
    liste_i = [] #each line of the array
    for i in liste:
        if liste_i :
            array1.append(liste_i)
            liste_i = []
        for j in liste:
            if dico.has_key(i+"/"+j): 
                liste_i.append(dico[i+"/"+j])
            elif dico.has_key(j+"/"+i):
                liste_i.append(dico[j+"/"+i])
            else :
                liste_i.append(0)
    array1.append(liste_i)
    print array1
    matrix = np.array(array1)
    print matrix.shape()
    print matrix
    return matrix
    
make_array(liste,dico)
```

Thanks a lot, for you answers, using `in dico` or list comprehensions does improve the speed of the script, and this was very helpfull.
But It seems that my problem is caused by the following function:

```
def clustering(matrix, liste_globale_occurences, output2):
    most_common_groups = []
    Y = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(matrix)
    Z = scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage(Y,'average', 'euclidean')
    scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram(Z)
    clust_h = scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster(Z, t = 15, criterion='distance')
    print clust_h
    print len(clust_h)
    most_common = collections.Counter(clust_h).most_common(3)
    group1 = most_common[0][0]
    group2 = most_common[1][0]
    group3 = most_common[2][0]
    most_common_groups.append(group1)
    most_common_groups.append(group2)
    most_common_groups.append(group3)
    with open(output2, 'w') as results: # here the begining of the problem 
        for group in most_common_groups: 
            for i, val in enumerate(clust_h):
                if group == val:
                    mise_en_page = "{0:36s} groupe co-occurences = {1:5s} \n"
                    results.write(mise_en_page.format(str(liste_globale_occurences[i]),str(val)))
```

When a small file is used, i get correct results, for instance :

> contact a = groupe 2
>
> contact b = groupe 2
>
> contact c = groupe 2
>
> contact d = groupe 2
>
> contact e = groupe 3
>
> contact f = groupe 3

But when a heavy file is used, i only get one example per group :

> contact a = groupe 2
>
> contact a = groupe 2
>
> contact a = groupe 2
>
> contact a = groupe 2
>
> contact e = groupe 3
>
> contact e = groupe 3

Comment: Can you explain more about *build a matrix with a list and then fill it up with the values of dict.*? maybe with showing a minimal example!

Comment: Don't use `has_key` it is deprecated in 2.7 and removed in 3, Use `in dico`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a matrix mat=len(liste)*len(liste) of zeros and go through your dico and split key: val before '/' will be number of row and val after '/' will be number of column. At this way you don't need to use 'has_key' search function.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like an O(n<sup>2</sup>) cause you have want to get all the combinations from `liste` with itself. So you have to have an inner loop.

What you can try and do is write each line to a file and then in a new process afterwards, create the matrix from the file. The new process would use less memory cause it won't have to store your large inputs of `liste` and `dico`. So something like this:

```
def make_array(liste,dico):
    f = open('/temp/matrix.txt', 'w')
    for i in liste:
        for j in liste:
            # This is just short circuit evaluation of logical or. It gets the first value that's not nothing
            f.write('%s ' % (dico.get(i+"/"+j) or dico.get(j+"/"+i) or 0))
        f.write('\n')
    f.close()
    return
```

Then once this has executed you can call

```
print np.loadtxt('/temp/matrix.txt', dtype=int)
```

I have used short circuit evaluation to reduce the lines of code of your `if` statements. In fact, if you use [list comprehensions](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-python/) you can reduce your `make_array` function to this:

```
def make_array(liste,dico):
    return np.array([[dico.get(i+"/"+j) or dico.get(j+"/"+i) or 0 for j in liste] for i in liste])
```